# c# array printing elements of multiple arrays

Tags: c#, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Here is my code thus far; my main problem is in the main method.

```
namespace Lab
{
    class dailyMenu
    {
        public static int r;
        public string day;
        public int date;
        public string entree;
        public double price;
        public int calories;


        public static int assignDate = 1;

        public string Day
        {
            get { return day; }
            set { day = value; }
        }
        public int Date
        {
            get { return date; }
            set { date = value; }
        }
        public string Entree
        {
            get { return entree; }
            set { entree = value; }
        }

        public double Price
        {
            get { return price; }
            set { price = value; }
        }

        public int Calories
        {
            get { return calories; }
            set { calories = value; }
        }



        private static string[] DayArray = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" , "Saturday" , "Sunday" };
        private static string[] EntreeArray = { "Pizza", "Spaghetti", "Cheeseburger", "Salad", "Soup", "Sandwich", "Pork", "Roast Chicken", "Kebab", "Steak", "Tacos", "Risotto" };

        private static double[] PriceArray = { 2.50, 4.00, 1.50, 1.50, 1.50, 3.00, 3.50, 3.00, 2.50, 4.00, 3.00, 2.00 };
        private static int[] CalorieArray = { 300, 600, 650, 270, 190, 680, 250, 300, 180, 250, 350, 600 };

        public static void DayofMonth(int date)
        {
            date = assignDate;
            assignDate++;


                if (date == 5 || date == 12 || date == 19 || date == 26)
            {
                assignDate += 2;
            }//end if

        }// end DateofMonth

        public static void DayofWeek (int day)
        {
            day = (day % 7) - 1;
        }// end DayofWeek

        public void randomItem()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            r = rnd.Next(0, 12);

            this.entree = EntreeArray[r];
            this.calories = CalorieArray[r];
            this.price= PriceArray[r];

        }// end randomItem

        public dailyMenu()
        {
         randomItem();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   
            // Populates the 2D array
            dailyMenu [,] day = new dailyMenu [4, 5];
            for (int row = 0; row < 4; row ++)
            {
                for (int column = 0; column < 5; column++)
                {
                    day[row, column] =  new dailyMenu();
                    for (int i; r < Length.day; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(r);
                    }

                }//end forloop column
            }// end forloop row
        }//end Main
    }//end dailyMenu
}//end namespace
```

I am trying to print out a new instance of DailyMenu with the three arrays using a for loop in Main, however the error message I'm getting is "The name Length does not exist in the current context."

Any help, please? Thanks.

Comment: It's pretty clear...you haven't defined a variable called `Length` anywhere.

Comment: I think you mean `day.Length` instead of `Length.day`, but you also have not refined `r`.  Did you mean `i`?  Finally, `Length` for a 2-D array will give you the size of the entire array, not just one dimension.

Comment: Just because I'm interested: What do you *think* that code would print? And are you *sure* you need a multi-dimensional array of your main class? So many questions about your code :-) Welcome to StackOverflow, I guess you'll soon have new questions.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar - I've populated the day array with dailyMenu, which should print from the calorie array, the entree array, and the price array, since they all are parallel arrays. Since the question I've changed "Console.WriteLine(r)" to "Console.WriteLine(EntreeArray [r] + "  " + CalorieArray [r] + "  " + PriceArray [r])." Which does work, but I'm getting a print of each of the array items for the length of "day," e.g. "Pizza 2.50 300" 20 times.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `day.Length` not `Length.day`.  `day` is your variable -- an array -- and it has a `Length` property.

Comment: Yep, this fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

One of the biggest problem I see with your code has to do with correctly naming your variables. Your class has a String property named 'day', you also declare a dailyMenu variable named 'day' in your main function and you also have an int parameter named 'day' in the DayOfWeek function. Talk about not helping with confusion. Name your things properly and you will have less problems.